# Does jdbc provide a way to read the database process id/session id for a given connection?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, liquibase, ojdbc

I am trying to use liquibase for database changes(we are using oracle) and one of the requirements our DBA put forward was to log the ospid and db session id of the jdbc connection so that they can kill it manually should the need arise. I looked through the java.sql.Connection interface and it doesn't seem to be an option available to retrive those values from jdbc connection. Did i miss something ? I would very much appreciate if someone can point out a way to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the SID and the OS process ID of the current session through a query:

```
SELECT s.sid, p.spid
FROM v$session s
JOIN v$process p ON p.addr = s.paddr 
WHERE sid=sys_context('USERENV','SID') ;
```

You DBA has to grant you the access to V$SESSION and V$PROCESS.

However, I don't really understand the requirement. If a session is causing problems the DBA is the first to know which one through Oracle Enterprise Manager.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding
If you execute the following query from your JDBC connection, it will give you the information you need

```
SELECT s.sid, s.serial#, p.spid, s.osuser, s.program FROM v$session s, v$process p WHERE p.addr = s.paddr and s.sid in (select distinct sid from v$mystat)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware oracle had this info and i could get this info via a query  provided i had access to the views above. What  i wanted to know was if there is a way to get it from jdbc/driver side. It could be that my requirement is specific to oracle and a common definition of connection process id on database server doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the JDBC API itself to get this information. You will need to use either driver-specific extensions, or query the information, as shown by the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Today, me too got into the situation to find which thread is running with which Oracle session id. Basically, I am using the connection pool, to get connection in multithreads, and was doing write I/O to a global temp table (GTT), in each thread. The data written in one thread would not be visible to other thread if the session ids are different.
So, while doing that I got a need to know which thread (having its own connection) is using which SID. I found that it is possible by sending tag from  Java side in setClientInfo and then we can see in DB query select module, sid from v$session. Actual steps would be:

1. In the java side, after getting the connection, set the client info

   Connection con = dbcpDs.getConnection();
   con.setClientInfo("E2E_CONTEXT.MODULE","threadid");
2. Then run the code and in the db side while it is running you can query like
   select module, sid from v$session
   And we know which java thread, connection mapped to which Oracle SID. Now from java side we can query the v$session with where module ="threadid" and get it at runtime in java as well!